# Calling from dictionary of dates as keys

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the format:

```
{'12/12/1980' : ['28.75', '28.87', '28.75', '28.75', '2093900.0', '0.0', '1.0']}
```

Using the datetime module, I need to be able to iterate through the dictionary over a range of dates and call on an index within the value/list attached to each key.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
delta = date_sold - date_bought
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print (date_bought + td(days=i))
```

My major problem is that it is outputting the date and the time like so:

```
1980-12-12 00:00:00
1980-12-13 00:00:00
1980-12-14 00:00:00
1980-12-15 00:00:00
1980-12-16 00:00:00
1980-12-17 00:00:00
1980-12-18 00:00:00
1980-12-19 00:00:00
1980-12-20 00:00:00
```

I need it to output is as in the format MM/DD/YYYY so that I can use the dates produced to call on my dictionary keys.

The function must output the dates like so:

```
12/12/1980
12/13/1980
12/14/1980
```

etc...

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a format.
Check this
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime
See the examples and adapt to your needs
(Edit: typos)